# "Percona-XtraDB-Cluster prohibits use of ALTER command on a table (<example>) that resides in non-transactional storage engine"

Tags: mysql, migration, mysqldump, percona, xtradb-cluster

I installed a Percona XtraDB cluster with `pxc_strict_mode` set to `ENFORCING`, and am trying to import databases from non-Galera MariaDB servers. This works fine for some databases, by dumping them via `mysqldump --skip-locks -K` and importing them via `mysql <database> < <dumpfile>` (after creating a blank database using `CREATE DATABASE`).
One database however is refused the import:

> ERROR 1105 (HY000) at line 40: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster prohibits use of ALTER command on a table (example.example) that resides in non-transactional storage engine (except switching to transactional engine) with pxc_strict_mode = ENFORCING or MASTER

Most internet threads simply suggest temporarily disabling `pxc_strict_mode`. Given however that other databases import without any issues, I assume the issue should be resolvable by altering either the the flags appended to `mysqldump`, or modifying the statements inside the dumpfile. I attempted removing all ALTER statements in the dump, which changes the above error to `...prohibits the use of DML command...`.

Both, the source MariaDB instance, as well as the new XtraDB Cluster, are configured with the default InnoDB storage engine.

Would appreciate any input.

Comment: Have you checked the storage engine of your table `example.example`? You can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE example.example;` or `SELECT engine FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='example' AND table_name='example';`

Comment: Interesting! Thank you. The tables in this database use MyISAM for some reason. I expected all databases and tables to be using InnoDB. I assume I would have to try converting the affected tables to InnoDB prior to migrating them.

Comment: The error message you posted above says it allows ALTER TABLE if the alteration is to change the table's storage engine to InnoDB: `ALTER TABLE example.example ENGINE=InnoDB;`

Comment: Thank you. Altering the offending tables to use InnoDB prior to dumping the database did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cluster can properly handle only InnoDB tables.  It sounds like some of your tables have `ENGINE=MyISAM`?

Plan A:  Edit the dump file to change to ENGINE=InnoDB for each table.

Plan B:  Remove the offending ALTERs; load the data (assuming the tables successfully convert to InnoDB); then manually run the lost ALTERs.

Plan C:  ALTER TABLE t ENGINE=InnoDB; for each table *before* dumping.

Each has potential hiccups.  Some are listed here:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: Thank you for your input. Whilst Plan B did not work, as explained in my original post, it caused the error to change to complaints about DML, Plan C worked perfectly. albeit possibly involved risks.